# Error adding DS records for my subdomain to the zone file of parent domain - using bind

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, domain, bind

I have domain example.company.com which is DNSSEC secured and has sent its DS records to the parent company.com. I want to create 2 other subdomains, both DNSSEC secured, sub1.example.company.com and sub2.example.company.com. However the parent domain here is example.company.com and not company.com so I want to include the DS records for the subdomains in the zone file for example.company.com.

However when I add the DS records manually and try to resign example.company.com using the same keys as before (unexpired) I get the following error

```
dnssec-signzone: fatal: dnssec-signzone: fatal: 'sub1.example.company.com': found DS RRset without NS RRset
```

What am I doing wrong here, alternatively how can I ensure DNSSEC protection from my subdomains given my existing main domain (example.company.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DS` records are only used as part of delegations between zones, ie side by side with the `NS` records that define such a delegation.

If you have for example the zone `example.com` and just add records for `foo.example.com` or `foo.bar.example.com` to this zone that is already covered as it is part of the same zone.

However, if you delegate eg `sub.example.com` so that this is a separate zone, you would have BOTH `NS` and `DS` records for `sub.example.com` in the `example.com` zone.

I'm not sure which of the cases above this question describes, but either you are missing the `NS` records for the delegation of the new zone or you are trying to add superfluous `DS` records "within" a zone.

Additionally, I would strongly suggest using the [integrated DNSSEC signing support in BIND](https://ftp.isc.org/isc/dnssec-guide/html/dnssec-guide.html#easy-start-guide-for-authoritative-servers) (`auto-dnssec maintain` and if needed the `inline-signing` config options) rather than the older external `dnssec-signzone` tool.

Comment: my situation was your 2nd scenario, I missed the NS records and added them. sub.example.com and example.com belong to different zones owned by me. But if I go with the DNSSEC support option from bind, how do I ensure the subdomains are correctly signed? just add the DS / NS from sub.example.com in the example.com zone file and let the signatures be refreshed accordingly?

Comment: You would just do the same thing for each zone, I suppose. Configure the zone and add keys, validate that the signing works, then add `DS` to the already signed parent.